# Bash alias problem

Tags: bash, grep, alias

I can't understand why using alias prompts an error, but using the same syntax without alias does not...

```
alias grep='egrep -iIs '
19:47:24 ~
cat /etc/services | \grep ssh
ssh     22/tcp              # SSH Remote Login Protocol
19:47:26 ~
cat /etc/services | grep ssh
grep: option requires an argument -- 'X'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
19:47:33 ~
cat /etc/services | egrep -iIs ssh
ssh     22/tcp              # SSH Remote Login Protocol
```

Can you explain this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce it - works fine here on Fedora24.

Comment: Works fine for me with GNU grep but note that `-I` is not POSIX.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux 17.04

Comment: what does `type -a grep egrep` show?

Comment: type -a grep egrep <br>
grep is aliased to `egrep -iIs ' <br>
grep is /bin/grep <br>
egrep is /bin/egrep

Comment: Can not reproduce on Ubuntu 17.04 with the information given. No error.

Comment: Do `set -x` and try it again.

Comment: Do you by any chance also have `ssh` aliased to `ssh -X`? if so, I suspect the trailing space in your `alias grep='egrep -iIs '` is allowing *that* to be expanded to `ssh -X` - resulting in the additional `-X` argument being passed to `grep`

Comment: @steeldriver That's the only possible reason, you should make this an answer.

Comment: @xhienne done - let's see if the OP confirms the hypothesis

Comment: I bet I'm not the only one to wonder what may be that unknown `-X` option to `grep`. So [here is the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392341/203203)... along with further questions.

Comment: @steeldriver Thats it! Well done & many thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in the `ALIASES` section of `man bash`

> If  the
>          last  character  of  the  alias value is a blank, then the next command
>          word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

Since you have defined your `grep` alias with such a blank last character, the shell will also expand any alias that you have defined for `ssh` - if that is `alias ssh='ssh -X'` for example, then the command will become

```
cat /etc/services | egrep -iIs ssh -X
```

which passes the `-X` as an additional argument to `egrep`.

Unless there is a particular reason to include the trailing blank, simply define the alias without it, i.e.

```
alias grep='egrep -iIs'
```