# What is the actual purpose of GNU grep's -X option and why is it undocumented?

Tags: grep, options

By reading [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392275/203203), I have discovered that GNU `grep` has a `-X` option which expects an argument. Strangely, it is mentioned neither in the man page nor in the info page.

Looking at the source code, there is that comment [right in the middle of the `--help` output](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?id=dbf6efe68c6d97a66ad20a4d5d2935a520bf4bd7#n1925):

```
/* -X is deliberately undocumented.  */
```

Looking further, it appears that the `-X matcher` option [sets the engine used for the regexp](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?id=dbf6efe68c6d97a66ad20a4d5d2935a520bf4bd7#n2504), `matcher` being [one of](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/src/grep.c?id=dbf6efe68c6d97a66ad20a4d5d2935a520bf4bd7#n2012) `grep`, `egrep`, `fgrep`, `awk`, `gawk`, `posixawk` and `perl` (as of version 2.25).

Some of those values are strictly identical to existing options (namely `grep -G`, `grep -E`, `grep -F` and `grep -P`). On the other hand, the three `awk` variants have no corresponding options.

Does someone know what is the actual purpose of this option, especially with one of the `awk` regexp engines? Can someone tell me why it is purposely not documented?

Comment: Interesting discovery!  I suspect the purpose of leaving it undocumented is so that they can feel free to remove it from future versions at will and without notice.  Another example of a GNU undocumented option is `-E` for GNU sed which provides compatibility with BSD sed.  (I expect `-E` to become documented if POSIX formally adopts it and removed if it doesn't.)

Comment: I agree with @John1024, although the only person who can definitively answer is Stepan Kasal, who, on 7 February 2005, documented that `-X` is deliberately undocumented.  (His email address is in the changelog if you want to ask him.)

Comment: I tried to track this down through the git history, but it turns out it was added before grep's first git commit (it was present in 06b9f7e683e7650804cadd9a4c5cf6bff6c89625 from Tue Nov 3 21:38:52 1998). Presumably they imported the previous VCS into git, as obviously that predates git.

Comment: Also in grep 2.0 which is the oldest to be found at http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grep/?C=M;O=A

Comment: ... but not in 1.6 which I found at http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/distributions/TAMU/TAMU-1.0D/src/tar/grep-1.6.tar.gz (note: I have made no effort to verify the authenticity of that code) so it'd appear to date to somewhere between 1.6 (1992) and 2.0 (1993)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Its purpose is to provide access to the various matchers implemented in GNU `grep` in one form or another, in particular AWK matchers which aren’t available otherwise, probably for testing purposes (see [bug 16481](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=16481) which discusses adding the `gawk` and `posixawk` matchers).

However it is currently buggy, which [is the reason why it’s documented as being undocumented](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2005-01/msg00063.html):

> On Thu, Jan 27, 2005 at 04:06:04PM -0500, Charles Levert wrote:
>   > The '-X' option, and in particular its use with the "awk" matcher
>   > ("-X awk") is undocumented.
>
> please leave it undocumented.
>
> It doesn't provide any new functionality besides -X awk.
>
> And the implementation of awk regexps is not perfect, I think.
>
> The new GNU regex conatins some means to set AWK style syntax, yes.
>   Yet gawk doesn't use it directly: it parses the regex first.
>
> In particular, awk regexps allow escape sequences \NNN, where NNN is
>   an octal value. So /\040/ mathes space. grep -X awk doesn't seem to
>   support this.
>
> I'm afraid that regex.c doesn't support these escape sequences.
>
> We would have to make sure that the regexes are fully compatible with
>   awk regexes before we decided to document (and thus support) this
>   feature.
>
> I think it's not worth the trouble.
>
> Stepan

A [follow-up](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2005-01/msg00071.html) asked for the comment to be added, and provided a bit more background on the `-X` option:

> My own inclination is to suggest just removing -X entirely. I suspect it was added by the original author mainly for testing purposes. If it's going to stay in, at least add a comment like this.
>
> ```
> /* -X is undocumented on purpose. */
> ```
>
> to avoid future discussion of a resolved issue.
>
> Arnold

which [Stepan did shortly thereafter](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-grep/2005-02/msg00004.html).

Comment: Nice archaeological work, thank you Stephen.

Comment: Thanks :-). The trail stops at grep 2.0 unfortunately; I get the impression that’s the version which introduced `-X`, probably as a side-effect of the DFA rewrite, but the changelog is short on details.

Comment: "to avoid future discussion of a resolved issue."  How'd that work out? ;)

Comment: Wouldn't "-X is undocumented because it's buggy" have been a better choice?